# Prove that every bipartite graph G has a matching of size ≥ |E(G)|/∆, where ∆ is the maximum degree of G.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Prove that every bipartite graph G has a matching of size ≥ |E(G)|/∆, where ∆ is the
maximum degree of G. **Using Halls Theorem.** I need a good proof, I am studying for an exam and I need to understand very deeply.

Comment: The standard proof of this is via Konig's theorem. I do not know of a proof using Hall's theorem directly (if that is what your phrasing of the question implies), but you may want to take a look at the [deficient Hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficiency_(graph_theory)#:~:text=Moreover%2C%20using%20the%20notion%20of,vertices%20of%20X%20are%20unmatched.), which can be proved using Hall's theorem.